# VBA Copying Newer Files from one location to another using SHFileOperation

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code to copy files from one location to another in Access 2010 and is working fine. The problem I'm having is copying just the **new files** to the destination. I do **not** want to override the files, only copy new files.
Here is my code:

```
Public Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long

Private Const FO_COPY = &H2
Private Const FO_DELETE = &H3 
Private Const FO_MOVE = &H1
Private Const FO_RENAME = &H4
Private Const FOF_ALLOWUNDO = &H40
Private Const FOF_CONFIRMMOUSE = &H2
Private Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0
Private Const FOF_FILESONLY = &H80
Private Const FOF_MULTIDESTFILES = &H1
Private Const FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = &H10
Private Const FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR = &H200
Private Const FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = &H8
Private Const FOF_SILENT = &H4
Private Const FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = &H100
Private Const FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE = &H20

Public Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Long
    hNameMappings As Long
    lpszProgressTitle As Long
End Type

Public Sub VBCopyFolder(ByRef strSource As String, ByRef strTarget As String)
Dim op As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

With op
    .wFunc = FO_COPY
    .pTo = strTarget
    .pFrom = strSource
    .fFlags = FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS
End With

'~~> Perform operation
SHFileOperation op
End Sub
```

I call the subroutine like so

```
 Call VBCopyFolder("O:\fieldticket\pdf\", "\\rwmain01\gis\FieldTicket\")
```

Comment: Other alternative: `Shell "xcopy /D ..."` or even Robocopy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option you can try.  You will have to iterate through the files though. So, it will potentially be slow over time if you have a large number of files building up.

```
Public Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fils As Scripting.Files
    Dim fil As Scripting.File

    Dim strSourceFolder As String
    Dim strDestFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    On Error GoTo err_Proc

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strSourceFolder = "O:\fieldticket\pdf\"
    strDestFolder = "\\rwmain01\gis\FieldTicket\"

    If Not fso.FolderExists(strSourceFolder) Then GoTo exit_Proc

    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)

    For Each fil In fld.Files
        ' Process the file with logic you consider new
        If fil.DateCreated > Now - 1 Then
            fso.CopyFile fil.Path, strDestFolder & fil.Name
            DoEvents
        End If

        ' Or just try to copy it over with overwrite set to false
        'fso.CopyFile fil.Path, strDestFolder & fil.Name, False
    Next

exit_Proc:
    Set fil = Nothing
    Set fils = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err_Proc:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    GoTo exit_Proc
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fils As Scripting.Files
    Dim fil As Scripting.fILE                                                                               it says compile error: user-defined type not defined

Comment: You need to add a reference to reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  Under menu Tools>References check off Microsoft Scripting Runtime.